# AWS CDK not deploying API Gateway change (EDGE to REGIONAL)

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm experimenting with AWS CDK by converting a console-developed application (just API Gateway and Lambdas for now). All is well--I can hit the API's resources and methods and the appropriate lambdas get executed.

I'm trying to understand what triggers a deployment (and what doesn't). For example, if I try to change the API's endpoint type from the default (EDGE) to REGIONAL:

```js
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, "cy-max-api", {
    restApiName: "CY Max Service",
    description: "CDK version of Max AWS demo app.",
    endpointConfiguration: [EndpointType.REGIONAL] // <-- add only this line and deploy
});
```

and deploy (`cdk deploy`), nothing is deployed (I checked the logs, console says no stack changes). I even tried forcing the deploy (`cdk deploy -f`)--no joy.

I suspect this is the expected behavior, but would like to understand why this change doesn't trigger a deploy (and what would be necessary to force one).

**Update** based on response by @balu-vyamajala (thanks for taking the time to test it).
I am using version 1.82.0 of the CDK. Here's the result of `cdk diff` when the only change is adding the `endpointConfiguration` line:

```
Stack CyMaxStack
Resources
[-] AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment CyMaxcymaxapiDeploymentD64E3EA0186ed2bffe1dbc3004a8457d0ce5eb28 destroy
[+] AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment CyMax/cy-max-api/Deployment CyMaxcymaxapiDeploymentD64E3EA0cd62c1e6cd1229987f977199cc5906ea
[~] AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi CyMax/cy-max-api CyMaxcymaxapi48ECF39D
 └─ [+] EndpointConfiguration
     └─ {}
[~] AWS::ApiGateway::Stage CyMax/cy-max-api/DeploymentStage.prod CyMaxcymaxapiDeploymentStageprod5291AAF0
 └─ [~] DeploymentId
     └─ [~] .Ref:
         ├─ [-] CyMaxcymaxapiDeploymentD64E3EA0186ed2bffe1dbc3004a8457d0ce5eb28
         └─ [+] CyMaxcymaxapiDeploymentD64E3EA0cd62c1e6cd1229987f977199cc5906ea
```

and here's what `cdk deploy` says:

```
CyMaxStack: deploying...
[0%] start: Publishing 6280a7c7fbc87dd62aeb85e098d6de2f0b644eea442dcbfc67063a56c08ce151:current
[100%] success: Published 6280a7c7fbc87dd62aeb85e098d6de2f0b644eea442dcbfc67063a56c08ce151:current
CyMaxStack: creating CloudFormation changeset...
[█████████████████████████████·····························] (5/10)



 ✅  CyMaxStack

Outputs:
CyMaxStack.CyMaxcymaxapiEndpoint52D905B0 = https://...my URL...

Stack ARN:
arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-1:...my ARN...
```

When I check the console the API has not been updated to `REGIONAL`. Also, `endpointConfiguration` is either missing, or `{}` in `cdk.out/tree.json`. I never see `{REGIONAL}` in that file.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are asking about update to AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment which doesn't automatically happen and cdk generates a hash of methods and resources to append to resource name to force deployment.
But in your case, EndpointConfiguration is a property of AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi which is directly referred in AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment. Irrespective of any other changes, it must trigger a new Deployment.

which version of cdk you are using?

I just tested it with 1.80.0, it did trigger a change in three resources AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment, AWS::ApiGateway::Stage and AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi.

Please try cdk synth and observe generated CloudFormation for resource AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi before and after compiling your change

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but for anyone facing the same problem:

1. If you want the changes to auto-deploy, make sure `deploy` property is set to `true` in the RestApi parameters. By default it is, but you might have accidentally modified it or you have some setup that makes it false/undefined.

```
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, "cy-max-api", {
    restApiName: "CY Max Service",
    description: "CDK version of Max AWS demo app.",
    endpointConfiguration: [EndpointType.REGIONAL],
    deploy: true
});
```

2. There is a known limitation on the changes being deployed: the api model gets hashed and that hash determines if there will be a new deployment. Not all properties end up influencing the hash. The workaround is to make a new deployment with a new logical id, so the CDK is forced to deploy. For me, just modifying the latest deployment (`apiGateway.latestDeployment?.addToLogicalId(Date.now());`) worked, even without creating my own. There is a lot of details about the problem in [this github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/13526).

Also, pointing out just in case because it got me confused: "Deployment" in this code refers to [APIGW Deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api.html) (the one you see in the console by going to stage => deployment history and can trigger by clicking "deploy" in apigw resources tab), not the `cdk deploy` and consequent CF stack deployment.